# Creating Classes From Props & Prop Values in VueJS

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I am looking to create a columns component in VueJS that will look something like this:

```
<column-i xs="3" md="6" lg="12">
  Some Content
</column-i>
```

When rendered, I would like the html markup to look like this:

```
<div class="column xs3 md6 lg12>Some Content</div>
```

In other words, I want to concatenate the prop name and its value together and then add the concatenated string to the class attribute -- and I'm having a hard time figure out how to do that.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

If all the properties of the component will be used, you can use [`Object.entries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) and `this.$props` to get an array of all the `[key, value]` pairs. Then, iterate the array in a computed property to construct the classes which will be bound to the component's element.

```js
const ColumnI = {
  name: 'column-i',

  template: `<div :class="columnClass"><slot /></div>`,

  // Define the props that will be converted into classes
  props: {
    xs: {
      Type: Number,
      default: null,
    },

    md: {
      Type: Number,
      default: null,
    },

    lg: {
      Type: Number,
      default: null,
    },
  },

  computed: {
    columnClass() {
      let result = ['column']
      // Look for all the component props and get an array of all its
      // enumerable [key, value] pairs
      for (let [propKey, propValue] of Object.entries(this.$props)) {
        // If the prop has a value
        if (propValue) {
          // Add the prop to the class as '<key><value>'
          // ie. xs prop with a value of 3 results in 'xs3'
          result.push(`${propKey}${propValue}`)
        }
      }
      return result
    },
  },
}

new Vue({
  el: '#app',

  components: {
    ColumnI,
  }
})
```

```css
/*
 Random styles just for illustration purposes
*/

.column {
  padding: 10px;
}

.xs3 {
  color: dodgerblue;
}

.md6 {
  background-color: whitesmoke;
}

.lg12 {
  border: 2px solid tomato;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <column-i xs="3" md="6" lg="12">
    Some Content
  </column-i>
</div>
```

---

The above solution does not handle adding props, that will not be bound as a class, to the component.

To handle that, we can create an array of the breakpoints we want to convert to a class.

```js
const ColumnI = {
  name: 'column-i',

  template: `<component :is="tag" :class="columnClass"><slot /></component>`,

  props: {
    // This prop will not be converted into a class
    tag: {
      Type: String,
      default: 'div',
    },

    xs: {
      Type: Number,
      default: null,
    },

    md: {
      Type: Number,
      default: null,
    },

    lg: {
      Type: Number,
      default: null,
    },
  },

  data() {
    return {
      breakpoints: ['xs', 'md', 'lg'],
    }
  },

  computed: {
    columnClass() {
      let result = ['column']
      // Look for all the component props and get an array of all its
      // enumerable [key, value] pairs
      for (let [propKey, propValue] of Object.entries(this.$props)) {
        // If the prop is a breakpoint and it has a value
        if (this.breakpoints.includes(propKey) && propValue) {
          // Add the prop to the class as '<key><value>'
          // ie. xs prop with a value of 3 results in 'xs3'
          result.push(`${propKey}${propValue}`)
        }
      }
      return result
    },
  },
}

new Vue({
  el: '#app',

  components: {
    ColumnI,
  }
})
```

```css
/*
 Random styles just for illustration purposes
*/

.tagdiv {
  /* This will not be applied */
  text-decoration: underline;
}

.column {
  padding: 10px;
}

.xs3 {
  color: dodgerblue;
}

.md6 {
  background-color: whitesmoke;
}

.lg12 {
  border: 2px solid tomato;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <column-i xs="3" md="6" lg="12">
    Some Content
  </column-i>
</div>
```